# How to achieve data driven testing using postman and newman?

Tags: automation, postman, cypress, newman

I have a requirement to automate API`s and also integrate the same with Azure devOps pipeline. I am currently using Cypress and I am successful in doing so.

My clients wants to use postman for automation.

I have to run a single API with multiple combinations like different set of query parameters with different set of Request Body.

I know by using Cypress fixture we can achieve data driven testing, but can we do the same with Postman, if yes how can we integrate the same to Azure Pipeline for running different combinations of data?

Comment: `data-driven testing` using csv/json file in postman is terrible, but we can do a workaround like storing data in array of object, one request will take one object from array and run.

Comment: @lucasnguyen17 Can we integrate these requests to CI/CD like azure devops ? Where will these csv/json files be stored in that case ? and how to tell the request which csv/json file to pick and run?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. That's why data-driven in postman sucks. https://community.postman.com/t/passing-data-from-multiple-data-files-to-postman-collection-runner-or-newman/18515. You can follow the solution I mentioned before, if you want I can make a sample code for you.

Comment: @lucasnguyen17 hald knowledge is dangerous :) postman data driven testing is the easiest . you can run it in multple ways,

Answer (score 1):

data driven testing in postman is straight forward, csv header is the variable name :

create a csv file  called data.csv :

```
age
1
2
3
```

now call the varaible in any part like {{name}}

eg let request be :

```
{

"user": "{{name}}"

}
```

Now run the script using newman or collection runner. For cicd integration we should use newman. Export the collection as json and run

```
 newman run collection.json -d data.csv
```

thats it , at a single time you can use only one csv file , but can run the configuration using different csv file by rerunning command with different datafiles specified using -d

Comment: Yes, I know how to use csv file, but only one file at a time and I have many requests like this in the collection. One more thing, I have to separate this request from others in collection to reduce side effect of iteration. For example, I have a collection: req1, req2 (read csv file: 3 lines). When I run the collection with runner, I expect, req1 run 1 times, req2 3 times, but it turns out req1 3 times, req2 3 times. For me, it sucks.

Comment: Ok, this answers one of my questions. The other question is how do I integrate this with pipeline ? Where will the data.csv files be stored when we speak about CI/CD ?

Comment: @lucasnguyen17 you can easily do it , by using google sheet , or content in environment variable etc . try this , https://www.postman.com/praveendvd-public/workspace/postman-tricks-and-tips

Comment: @AbdullaSuhail it will saved along with collection and enovironment variablee .json files . You should have a folder with datafile, collection and environment

Comment: @lucasnguyen17 you should use postman.setNextRequest to control the flow

Comment: @PDHide Thanks, I understand your idea. To compare `data-driven test` in code, postman need to do some tricks to workaround, not directly solve it. Thanks for your time, anw.

Comment: Ok, so i have around 40 API calls with multiple sets of query parameters and requests body, i need to create 40 such excel files. each for each API ? Right ? From what i understand or is it more easy that this. ?

Comment: What do you mean by this ?
at a single time you can use only one csv file , "but can run the configuration using different csv file by rerunning command with different datafiles specified using -d "?

Comment: Just rerun the command Newman run collection -d first.csv